# Tub Drain connection: Tail piece vs Drain Wall Tube

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

I am switching out my Tub to freestanding type. Due to joist spacing the vertical part of the ptrap is about 4" away from the tub drain.

I checked with my plumbing inspector at the time of rough in and he said a short horizontal bit over is no problem as long as I keep a bit of slope. Now I am trying to decide between:

1. using a [drain wall tube](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-1-1-2-in-White-Plastic-Sink-Drain-Wall-Tube-HDC9006/316622080?) (typically used on a ptrap) to go from the tub to a 90d slip joint that goes into the vertical slip joint of the ptrap
2. slip jointing a tail piece into a 90d slip joint and then that 90d slip joint into the vertical slip joint of the ptrap. Basically pipe g [here](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/c5/c5b38f06-b708-4551-9166-6aac6acd1f2e.pdf).

I feel like 1 is better because less parts, but because of the reference product I found, I suspect I am wrong. So which option should I use?

Comparison of the parts necessary to connect to the tub drain:

[image: pipe pieces]